# In R, how to extracting two values from XML file, looping over 5603 files and write to table

Tags: xml, r, parsing, loops

As I am rather new to R, I am trying to learn how I can extract two values from a XML file and loop over 5603 other (small, <2kb) XML files in my working directory.

I have been reading a lot of topics on 'looping', but find this rather confusing - especially because it seems that looping over XML files is different from looping over other files, correct?

I am using online data in XML structure.

For each XML file I want to write the "ZipCode" and "AwardAmount" to a table.

Running the following code I did retrieve the ZipCode and AwardAmount, but only from the very first file. How can I write a proper loop and write it to a table?

```
xmlfiles=list.files(pattern="*.xml")
for (i in 1:length(xmlfiles)){
    doc= xmlTreeParse("xmlfiles[i]", useInternal=TRUE)
    zipcode<-xmlValue(doc[["//ZipCode"]])
    amount<-xmlValue(doc[["//AwardAmount"]])
}
```

Does anyone has some suggestions?

Comment: Well `"xmlfiles[i]"` is definitely not going to work. Try creating your file names using `paste(xmlfiles, seq_along(xmlfiles), sep = "")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might work for you.  I got rid of the `for` loop and went with `sapply`.

```
xmlfiles <- list.files(pattern = "*.xml")
txtfiles <- gsub("xml", "txt", xmlfiles, fixed = TRUE)
```

`txtfiles` is a set of new file names to be used as the output file for each run.

```
sapply(seq(xmlfiles), function(i){

  doc <- xmlTreeParse(xmlfiles[i], useInternal = TRUE)
  zipcode <- xmlValue(doc[["//ZipCode"]])
  amount <- xmlValue(doc[["//AwardAmount"]])
  DF <- data.frame(zip = zipcode, amount = amount)
  write.table(DF, quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, file = txtfiles[i])

})
```

Please, let me know if there are issues when you run it.

Answer (score 2):

Slightly different approach to Richard's (only slightly). Used `ldply` to make a data frame before writing it out to a file. You should select his for the answer since the "guts" of the `ldply` function is his, but this just shows an alternate way of doing it (assuming you want one file vs many files):

```
setwd("LOCATION_OF_XML_FILES")

xmlfiles <- list.files(pattern = "*.xml")

dat <- ldply(seq(xmlfiles), function(i){

  doc <- xmlTreeParse(xmlfiles[i], useInternal = TRUE)

  zipcode <- xmlValue(doc[["//ZipCode"]])
  amount <- xmlValue(doc[["//AwardAmount"]])

  return(data.frame(zip = zipcode, amount = amount))

})

head(dat)
##         zip amount
## 1 442420001  45000
## 2 479072114 400580
## 3 303320420  22050
## 4 326112002  12000
## 5 265066845  37000
## 6 168027000 300000

write.csv(dat, "zipamount.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

You could use `append=TRUE` with Richard's approach and use a single file name in that `write.table` to do the same thing. You can also tweak the output settings of `write.csv` (or `write.table`) to get the output format you eventually want to work with.

You can also add `recursive = TRUE` to the `list.files` to go through all the subdirectories vs put all ~5,600 files into one directory (that can have performance issues on some filesystems/operating systems).

Comment: hrbrmstr, thanks a lot for your comments. Using your method I was able to construct one file. Your comments helped me understand much better what is going one. Thank you.