# Running a loop on multiple xml files in one folder in R

Tags: r, xml, loops, xml-parsing

I am trying to run this script as a loop function as I have over 200 files in a folder and I am trying to produce one CSV file at the end listing all of the data that I need to extract.

I have tried various ways of running this in a loop e.g. [In R, how to extracting two values from XML file, looping over 5603 files and write to table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377350/in-r-how-to-extracting-two-values-from-xml-file-looping-over-5603-files-and-wr)

Whenever I do try these different options I get errors like:

Error: XML content does not seem to be XML or permission denied.

However, when I run the code selecting just one file it runs fine. These errors only seems to occur when I try convert it into a loop function for multiple files in a single folder.

Here is the original code used for a single file:

```
doc<-xmlParse("//file/path/32460004.xml")
xmldf <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes = getNodeSet(doc, "//BatRecord"))

df1 <- data.frame(xmldf)
df1 <- separate(df1, xmldf.DateTime, into = c("Date", "Time"), sep = " ")
df1$Lat <- substr(xmldf$GPS,4,12)
df1$Long <- substr(xmldf$GPS,13,25)
df_final <- data.frame(df1$xmldf.Filename, df1$Date, df1$Time, df1$xmldf.Duration, df1$xmldf.Temperature, df1$Lat, df1$Long)
colnames(df_final) <- c("Filename", "Date", "Time", "Call Duration", "Temperature", "Lat", "Long")

write.csv(df_final, "//file/path/test_file.csv")
```

Here is a link to some example files:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ZvmOEWhzlWHRl2GxZrbYY9y7YSZ5j9Fj?usp=sharing

Any help is appreciated.

Here is my version details:

```
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          6.3                         
year           2020                        
month          02                          
day            29                          
svn rev        77875                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
nickname       Holding the Windsock
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work using `tidyverse` and `xml2`.

```
require(tidyverse)
require(xml2)

### Put all your xml files in a vector
my_files <- list.files("path/to/your/xml/files", full.names = TRUE)

### Read function to transform them to tibble (similar to data.frame)
read_my_xml <- function(x, path = "//BatRecord") {
  tmp <- read_xml(x) # read the xml file
  tmp <- tmp %>% 
    xml_find_first(path) %>% # select the //BatRecord node
    xml_children # select all children of that node

  # this extracts the text of all children 
  # aka the text between the > TEXT </ Tags
  out <- tmp %>% xml_text 
  # Takes the names of the tags <NAME> ... </NAME>
  names(out) <- tmp %>% xml_name
  # Turns out to tibble - see https://stackoverflow.com/q/40036207/3301344
  bind_rows(out)
}

### Read the files as data

dat <- map_df(my_files, read_my_xml) # map_df is similar to a loop + binding it to one tibble

### To the transformation

dat %>% 
  separate(DateTime, into = c("Date", "Time"), sep = " ") %>% 
  mutate(Lat = substr(GPS,4,12), Long = substr(GPS,13,25)) %>% 
  write_csv("wherever/you/want/file.txt")
```

Comment: this is great. it works. thank you. is it possible to give an explanation as to what the code for the function to transform them to tibble is actually doing?

Comment: Added a step by step explanation - see above

Comment: What if the XML file also contains grandchildren, great-grandchildren, and more?